# NServicebus time-sensitive auction implementation

Tags: nservicebus

We are using NServicebus to design a system that has to solve an auction scenario: we want to send out a message to a set of companies that can bid on an item. After we've received all the bids we want to send the item to the highest bidder.

We initially thought this kind of scenario was perfectly suited for NServicebus: Pub/sub for sending out a message (e.g. BidOnItem or ItemAvailable), message handlers that subscribe to that message for each interested company and a saga for storing the different bids we receive and we're done.

In a normal auction we could set a timeout at say 5 minutes and then decide who gets the item based on the highest price we've received. We don't have that luxury. The problem that we've run in to is that our specific scenario has a tricky, non-negotiable business requirement: the auction is very time-sensitive. Seconds matter. What we'd like to do is decide who gets the item as soon as all companies have responded. Usually this will happen in a matter of seconds. We want to decide the second all subscribers have responded. Obviously we'll also still implement a timeout but that will be the exception rather than the rule. If we want to determine if everyone has replied we'd need something like a list  of all the handlers at all the endpoints that are subscribed to the BidOnItem message. It appears the NServicebus API doesn't provide this information.

There are some future requirements we have to implement as well centered around data enrichment and approval/rejection decisions that would benefit greatly from knowing whether all handlers on a pub/sub channel have responded. I know this reeks of request/reply which is something NServicebus discourages because of the coupling it causes but this requirement feels like something that's fundamental for a lot of processes that is very hard to implement outside of the core bus infrastructure. In that sense it feels a lot like Saga.ReplyToOriginator which NServicebus does provide.

What would be the "NServicebus Way" to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Pub/Sub is usually not the way to go in these auction scenarios. What if your saga would do reguest/response with your bidders?

S: OnAuctionCreated  (carries the list of bidders, or you could fetch them somewhere)
foreach bidder in event.Bidders
  -bus.Send(RequestBidFrom(bidder))
SetTimeout(X)

S: OnBidResponse
  bids.Add(response.Bidder,response.Bid)

if(bids.Count()== Data.TotalBidders)
    CompleteAuction();

S:OnTimeout
  CompleteAuction()

Comment: That looks like one of the "workarounds" we considered. The RequestBidFrom method in your example would return an instance of RequestBidFromCompanyX, RequestBidFromCompanyY, etc. and handlers to match those classes (optionally distributed over several endpoints) correct?

Comment: It depends on how different the requests are. I would probably use the same message and have a "integration" endpoint take care of mapping between the different bidders. That integration endpoint can then decide to use different messages for better scaling, monitoring etc  That integration endpoint could also be the one that keeps the list of active bidders. Remember that in messaging one request can result in multiple responses

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I see where you're going. It feels like we would be building something that pub/sub could give us for free. What we'd like to hear is why pub/sub is not the way to go here: is it because of limitations in the current NServicebus API or is it because it is inherently not a good pattern and if so, why?

Comment: One of the key principles of pub/sub is that the publisher should have no knowledge of its subscribers. It could be 0 or millions the publisher shouldn't care.  That is the reason that pub/sub is no good here given your requirement: "If we want to determine if everyone has replied". This requirement means that you have to know who is supposed to answer == reg/response. Does this help?